# Select rows with non matching column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve rows with same Volume value or with only 1 Volume, but could not come up with a SQL logic.

Data:

| ID | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| A | 100 |
| B | 101 |
| B | 102 |
| B | 103 |
| B | 104 |
| C | 400 |

Required Output:

| ID | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| A | 100 |
| C | 400 |

Comment: Either `HAVING MIN(volume) = MAX(volume)` or `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT volume) = 1` in subquery/CTE. `WHERE NOT EXISTS` can be used too.

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I did not add but Volume column can not be used on its own as it might have duplicates in other rows.

Comment: If there was a 3d row for ID=A with Volume=110 what would your expected result be?

Comment: @forpas I would not include ID=A in my results then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is achievable using a `subquery`.

```
select * from test where col1 in (
  select t.col1
  from(
    select col1, col2,
        dense_rank() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as dr
    from test) t
  group by  t.col1
  having sum(case when t.dr = 1 then 0 else t.dr end) = 0)
```

Try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=oDg5nRvzHi).

Comment: This works, Thanks. Where can I practice subqueries more?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on a more easy way:

```
select t1.id,
       t1.volume
from tbl t1
inner join (select id
            from tbl
            group by id
            having count(distinct volume) = 1
            ) as t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92bc234e631a1106b0e322bc4954d696

`having count(distinct volume) = 1` will return only the id that have the same volume , including the id with just one volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'd naturally be inclined towards [Ergest Basha's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72948704/53341) pattern.

It can also be expressed using `NOT EXISTS()`

```sql
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  tbl AS t
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM tbl
     WHERE id = t.id
       AND volume <> t.volume
  )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=243c42008f527391514d1ad124730587